# Simplifying external functions calls

Tags: c++

I have dozens of such functions, those are calls to some 3rd party external library. Is there any way to simplify it using some modern c++ feature? I want to avoid macros.

```cpp
class Renderer;
Renderer* pointer;

void DrawSetRedColor(int r) {
  using DrawSetRedColor_prototype = void(__thiscall**)(Renderer*, int);
  return (*(DrawSetRedColor_prototype)(*(DWORD*)pointer + 0x48))(pointer, r);
}

int DrawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
  using DrawLine_prototype = int(__thiscall**)(Renderer*, int, int, int, int);
  return (*(DrawLine_prototype)(*(DWORD*)pointer + 0x4C))(pointer, x0, y0, x1, y1);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a virtual call done manually. You should be able to define an interface (an abstract class with all methods pure virtual) with just the right vtable layout that would match that of the library class you are reverse-engineering.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is Indeed vtable, I can recreate those interfaces but it is quite complicated in some cases, when there are multiple inherited classes or when I need only one function at 1000 offset or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would probably work:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
R CallThroughVtable(void* pointer, size_t offset, Args... args) {
  using prototype = R (__thiscall**)(void*, Args...);
  return (*(prototype)(*(DWORD*)pointer + offset))(pointer, args...);
}

void DrawSetRedColor(int r) {
  CallThroughVtable<void>(pointer, 0x48, r);
}

int DrawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
  return CallThroughVtable<int>(pointer, 0x4C, x0, y0, x1, y1);
}
```

Comment: Some `enum` definitons for the magic numbers would make it perfect and less error prone, no?